# throwing an error -String indices must be integers

Tags: python, twitter

*#I did the same as you suggested the output at python shell is errors*

from rauth import OAuth1Service

```
twitter = OAuth1Service(
    name='twitter',
    consumer_key='2Xs6nzIL8r5yx4DQCxgg',
    consumer_secret='XXXXXXXX',
    request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
    base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1/')

request_token, request_token_secret = twitter.get_request_token()

authorize_url = twitter.get_authorize_url(request_token)

print 'Visit this URL in your browser: ' + authorize_url
pin = raw_input('Enter PIN from browser: ')

session = twitter.get_auth_session(request_token,
                                   request_token_secret,
                                   method='POST',
                                   data={'oauth_verifier': pin})

params = {'screen_name': '@nytimes',  # User to pull Tweets from
          'include_rts': 1,         # Include retweets
          'count': 10}              # 10 tweets

r = session.get('statuses/user_timeline.json', params=params)
```

## you asked for printing tweets only I did it here

```
for i, tweet in enumerate(r.json(), 1):
    print tweet
    #handle = tweet['user']['screen_name']
    #text = tweet['text']
    #print('{0}. @{1} - {2}'.format(i, handle, text))
```

Comment: print the `tweet` in the for loop. how does it look?

Comment: Salman its not working with for loop tracing the same error again. can you edit the exact for loop code you were talking about? Thanks for your reply

Comment: Do this,
`for i, tweet in enumerate(r.json(), 1):`
    `print(tweet)`

then you can see how is the `tweet` and why you are getting this error. And also paste it here.

Comment: Salman I did it the same way you showed here. but its sending the same message as i mentioned you in above code post

Comment: how is the `tweet`? only print `tweet` in the for loop and comment the other lines.

Comment: Salman after executing the code I showed above, I was getting the error: string indices must be integers

Comment: As you guided I try to print the Tweets only using for loop then the output comes errors in the python shell that is it.

Answer (score 0):

Either your `tweet` is a `str` or your `tweet` is a `dict` and your `tweet['user']` is a `str`.  You seem to expect that `tweet['user']` is a dict and try to index in that with `tweet['user']['screen_name']`.  This means that you are trying to index a `str` with another `str` which is not possible (as it makes no sense).  The resulting error message states exactly that:  `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

I suppose you give out your `tweet` and your `tweet['user']` (using `print tweet` and `print tweet['user']`, but do not give out both in the same print statement, otherwise an error in the second expression will prevent the output at all) to figure out what the data structures are here.  Then you probably know how to go on by yourself, or you post here again what you found out so we can go on helping.

Comment: Hi Alfe Thanks for your reply. Can you please type the edit part of the code for me in here?

Comment: Just insert `print tweet` and `print tweet['user']` in two separate lines before `handle = ...`.

Comment: I did the same Alfe but i got the same error Print tweet['user'] TypeError: String indices must be integers

Comment: Then the answer is: your `tweet` is a `str`, not a `dict`.  Print out `tweet` directly.  Maybe it is a _json_ encoded value?  Then you can decode it using `json.loads()`.  Maybe it is the text of the tweet directly?  Then you do not have the information about the handle etc. anymore.  Have a look at `tweet` itself to find out more!  I said so before but you didn't reply what the output of `tweet` was.

Comment: After printing the Tweets directly I get the results on python shell

Visit this URL in your browser: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorizeoauth_token=k4R8LfpOullLfaiyd8tZtDMcHMvcTVBhAzrHWz1iw8 Enter PIN from browser: xxxxxxxx errors

Comment: Could it be that you got an error message from twitter and now try to parse it as a valid result value? ;-)

Comment: Hi Alfe, I dont know whats wrong with the code in here. But I made another code for retrieving the tweets from any user using twython. Thanks for your help. I post one more code for getting term search from multiple users specified. thats throwing an error If you can help please